# Cannot show barcode appinventor personal server

Tags: android

i just installed App Inventor Personal server on my Server.

i change some configuration so that i can access it via internet, i edited file StartAI on line :

```
dev_appserver.sh --port=8888 --address=localhost war
```

be

```
dev_appserver.sh --port=8888 --address=175.103.44.182 war
```

With that i can access it over internet.Firstly, everything working well until i try to show barcode on application which i created before.

i got error message like bellow :

```
WARNING: ____Execution failure:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/aapt7537967590601193994": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.Execution.execute(Execution.java:103)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.Compiler.runAaptPackage(Compiler.java:796)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:411)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.ProjectBuilder.build(ProjectBuilder.java:161)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer.build(BuildServer.java:491)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer.buildAndCreateZip(BuildServer.java:442)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer.access$300(BuildServer.java:61)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer$1.run(BuildServer.java:382)
    at com.google.appinventor.buildserver.NonQueuingExecutor$1.run(NonQueuingExecutor.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    ... 11 more
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.Compiler runAaptPackage
WARNING: YAIL compiler - AAPT execution failed.
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.ProjectBuilder build
INFO: problem on Windows ProjectBuilder deleteRecursively/tmp/1346114061354_0.191825549629683-0
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer build
INFO: Build output: ________Preparing application icon<br>________Determining permissions<br>________Generating manifest file<br>________Compiling source files<br>(compiling appinventor/ai_test/Ezen/Screen1.yail to appinventor.ai_test.Ezen.Screen1)<br>(compiling /tmp/runtime4505406109072492881.scm to com.google.youngandroid.runtime)<br>Kawa compile time: 2.221 seconds<br>________Invoking DX<br>DX time: 19.628 seconds<br>________Invoking AAPT<br>YAIL compiler - AAPT execution failed.<br>
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer build
INFO: Build error output: Error: Your build failed due to an error in the AAPT stage, not because of an error in your program.

Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer checkMemory
INFO: Build 1 current used memory: 12038224 bytes
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer buildAndCreateZip
INFO: BuildServer.buildAndCreateZip test deleteOnExit
Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer buildAndCreateZip
SEVERE: Build 1 Failed: 1 Error: Your build failed due to an error in the AAPT stage, not because of an error in your program.

Aug 28, 2012 7:34:47 AM com.google.appinventor.buildserver.BuildServer$1 run
INFO: CallbackURL: http://localhost:8888/ode2/receivebuild/d6vwsnvx0m4qrm9oyr1pe1pcsnklpd0aicm39hkpf8tp5neuxl645orahzqcz88h1jsfdtoykdoaioxn9ky0y9b7ap8rdvqg9m4csz6qug683rfgu0ms7rdqs3x6unjckp5ywlmkph/build/Android
```

when i try to check on /tmp folder, there is no file or folder aapt7537967590601193994 inside.

What is it cause ? i have try to chown /tmp to my user and also give permission 777, but still same.

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and resolved it using these two lines:

-sudo apt-get install lib32z1
  -sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

I found the solution in an AppInventor forum somewhere but can't find it currently. Hope this can help someone out.